# How to validate XMLSchema using Xalan-C?

Tags: xalan

I'm using Xalan-C++ version 1.8. Is there any way to do schema validation. 
If so how to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Call  setUseValidation(true) method on Transformer object, before calling transform().